# accept spaces with user input in .Bat File?

Tags: file, batch-file, input, spaces

```
 set /p input= Please type the favorite color here:
 if /i "%input%"=="green and yellowz" goto :GREEN
 if %input%==red goto RED
 if %input%==yellow goto YELLOW
 if %input%==black goto BLACK
 Rem Check to see if input is green, red, yellow, or black, if it is one of 
 these then it will jump to the related point below.
 if not "%input%"==black goto ANOTHER
```

If the user inputs something with spaces, for example "not related" 
     the .Bat file exits itself, is there a way to accept user input even if it 
     has spaces in it, and isn't one of the options which I have declared for 
     them to choose?
solved by the comment below:

```
 set /p input= Please type the favorite color here:
 if /i "%input%"=="green and yellowz" goto :GREEN
 if /i "%input%"=="red" goto RED
 if /i "%input%"=="yellow" goto YELLOW
 if /i "%input%"=="black" goto BLACK
 Rem Check to see if input is green, red, yellow, or black, if it is one of 
 these then it will jump to the related point below.
 if not "%input%"=="black" goto ANOTHER
```

Comment: Can the bottom line of your snippet not just read `GoTo NONE`? As a side note, it is recommended that you always use the syntax you used for the first `If` command, not that used in the second, third, fourth and fifth; `If /I "%input%"=="MatchString"` _The doublequotes are also considered as part of each string in the comparison._

Comment: You fixed it, thanks so much.

Comment: @IroamaloneAtnight Using immediate expansion is not really a solution. See what happens with your modified batch file if you enter following string on prompt: `" == "" echo rd /S /Q "%TEMP%" & pause & echo "`. Your batch file suddenly executes commands not written at all in the batch file itself. Another example of user input: `"` because of pressing Shift+2 on German keyboard instead of just `2` and hitting key RETURN. The batch file execution is exited again by `cmd.exe` because of a syntax error on first line with an __IF__ command.

Answer (score 0):

The command line:

```
if %input%==red goto RED
```

is modified during preprocessing phase with user input `black white` to:

```
if black white == red goto RED
```

The Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` executing the batch file expects on this command line with internal command **IF** that there is a valid operator between first and third argument string.

Because of not using double quotes, the first argument string is after environment variable expansion `black` and the second argument string is `white` which is none of the supported operators as output on running in a command prompt window `if /?`. This results in an error message:

> white was unexpected at this time.

And next Windows command interpreter exits batch processing because of a syntax error as it can be seen on running the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file.

The command line above with `not related` as input string results in execution of the command line:

```
if not related == red goto RED
```

This is by chance a valid **IF** condition comparing if string `related` is **not** equal string `red` which is true and so `goto RED` is executed.

Use this batch code:

```
:EnterColor
set "input="
set /P "input=Please type the favorite color here: "
if not defined input goto EnterColor
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Check to see if input is green, red, yellow, or black. If it
rem is one of these then it will jump to the related point below.
if /I "!input!" == "green and yellow" endlocal & goto GREEN
if /I "!input!" == "red" endlocal & goto RED
if /I "!input!" == "yellow" endlocal & goto YELLOW
if /I "!input!" == "black" endlocal & goto BLACK
endlocal
goto ANOTHER
```

First the environment variable `input` perhaps already existing is deleted to make sure that this environment variable does not keep its value in case of user inputs nothing at all.

Then the user is prompted for the string. The user has the freedom to enter nothing at all or any string including a string containing a space or `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|>" `` together with other characters in any combination which means the user can input a string which next with immediate environment variable expansion in a command line results in executing one or more commands not written at all in the batch file.

For that reason delayed environment variable expansion is enabled and used on the following string comparisons to prevent modification of the command lines as written in the script by the string input by the user.

Comment: Thanks to you also, very helpful comment, I can see that you've put a lot of work into it, to explain it so well. Thanks again! I love Stackoverflow, so much friendly people.

Answer (score 0):

As `green` appears to take precedence over `yellow` in your submitted code, you may find that the following syntax and structure suits your purpose better.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set /P "input=Please type the favourite colour here: "
If /I Not "%input:green=%"=="%input%" GoTo GREEN
If /I Not "%input:red=%"=="%input%" GoTo RED
If /I Not "%input:yellow=%"=="%input%" GoTo YELLOW
If /I Not "%input:black=%"=="%input%" GoTo BLACK

:ANOTHER
Echo=Input string does not contain green, red, yellow, or black
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B

:GREEN
Echo=Input string contained green
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B

:RED
Echo=Input string contained red
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B

:YELLOW
Echo=Input string contained yellow
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B

:BLACK
Echo=Input string contained black
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
Exit /B
```

*What the `If` syntax does is replace any instance of `colour` in `%input%` with nothing meaning that `%input%` during its expansion will have changed upon a match and the `Not` `==` condition satisfied, `If /I Not "%input:colour=%"=="%input%" GoTo …`*

Comment: and an input of `predictive` will jump to `red`. (just a note; hard to avoid and probably not worth any additional code)

Comment: I know what you mean @Stephan, but as you know predictive isn't a colour? and to be fair, the only possibility I can think of off the top of my head which could be a problem based only on black, yellow, red or green would be **cultured** _(#F5F5F5)_, which isn't a red but contains the word red!

Comment: `not related` (explicitely listed in the question as input example) also isn't a colour. So there is no reason to expect only colour names as input.

Comment: One of the reasons I rarely write a batch script prompting for input using `Set /P` is exactly because the verification of all possible responses can be quite complicated and difficult to ensure robustness, especially because of spelling/typing errors and language differences.